# Read binary data as three UBYTE (8-bit Unsigned Byte) in MATLAB and use bit shift operators to get two 12 bit streams

Tags: matlab, bit-shift, 8-bit

I need to read the data as UBYTE (8-bit Unsigned Byte) in MATLAB and then used bit shift operators to get two 12-bit streams with 3600000 samples.  I have to do that by a command that the first two 12 bit values are contained in the first 3 UBYTEs, 8 bits from the first byte with the first 4 bits from the second byte, then the first 4 bits from byte 2 with all 8 bits from byte 3. Then the process repeats with the next 3 bytes (byte 4-6 etc.) and so on.

First 12 bit value:  byte 1 |+ (( byte 2 & 0xf0) << 4)

Second 12 bit value: (( byte 2 & 0xf) << 4) |+ ((byte 3 & 0xf0) >> 4) |+ ((byte 3 & 0xf) << 8)

How can I apply this command in **MATLAB**?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly then something like this might work:

```
% Some data for testing
data = randi([0, 256], 1, 9, 'uint8');

% Reshape data so two 12-bit values are in each column
data = reshape(data, 3, []);

m1 = uint16(hex2dec('0f'));
m2 = uint16(hex2dec('f0'));

first_values = uint16(data(1, :)) + bitshift(bitand(uint16(data(2, :)), m2), 4);
second_values = bitshift(bitand(uint16(data(2, :)), m1), 4) ...
  + bitshift(bitand(uint16(data(3, :)), m2), -4) ...
  + bitshift(bitand(uint16(data(3, :)), m1), 8);
```

I might have made a mistake with the masks, but the `bitshift` and `bitand` commands are probably what you are looking for.

The output is two arrays of unit16.  If you need the output to be a 12-bit type I'm not sure how best to do that in matlab.

Comment: Actually, I have to read 3 streams in a binary file and compare the values with a sample file.
Stream1: 3600000 Samples, 8-Bits, Start Location: 112
Stream2: 3600000 Samples, 12-Bits, Start Location: 3600112
Stream3: 3600000 Samples, 12-Bits, Start Location: 9000112

I read stream 1 easily by '*uint8'. But about stream2 and 3, I read them by 'ubit12=>uint16' and the values are 0 to 4095. But in the sample file, the values range are between 200 to 1000. When I asked my friend the reason for the difference between my values with the sample file, he advised as above
I must apply in MATLAB.